# builtins.ValueError: could not convert string to float

Tags: python

I have been attempting to turn the index of a list into a float so that I can append it to a new list for each iteration of the loop so that I can eventually take the minimum value of that final appended list. When I do something like

```
a = '4.34324'
f = float(a)
```

in the python shell, it seems to work fine, but I can't figure why this isn't working. For reference, tdlist is a list of lists, and when I do

```
print(TMINlist[tdlist.index(x)])
```

the output is the string

```
'60.6'
```

so I can't figure out why it won't convert it to a float. My code is below, and the problem is in line 8.

```
TMINlist = []
for pos in range(len(tdlist)):
    TMINlist.append(tdlist[pos][10])
TMINlist2 = []
for x in tdlist:
    if int(x[1][1]) == month:
        if x != '':
            a = (TMINlist[tdlist.index(x)])
            value = float(a)
            TMINlist2.append(value)
        else:
            continue
```

With the print(repr()) statement added, It returns this and the error:

```
'60.6'
''
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/liamm/Dropbox/Hw/Homework 5/hw5Part2.py", line 57, in 
  <module>
    value = float(a)
builtins.ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

An example snippet of the list is:

```
[['TROY LOCK AND DAM NY', ['2014', '01'], '18', '0', '-9', '6.8', '58', '2.16', '12.7', '19.8', '29.2', '10.4\n'], ['TROY LOCK AND DAM NY', ['2014', '02'], '20', '0', '-7', '12', '53', '4.08', '24.6', '22.2', '31.2', '13.4\n']]
```

Comment: Can you post the exact traceback? The ValueError prints the string you are trying to convert. Since it appears to be blank (nothing after the colon), I assume you are trying to convert an empty string, not `'60.6'`. If you add a `print(repr(TMINlist[tdlist.index(x)]))` just before the conversion, we can see what the value really is.

Comment: Learn to use a debugger and inspect values ... you'll find its far easier than remote StackOverflow debugging

Comment: could you post how is inside the list tdlist with all its values?

Comment: [['TROY LOCK AND DAM NY', ['2014', '01'], '18', '0', '-9', '6.8', '58', '2.16', '12.7', '19.8', '29.2', '10.4\n'], ['TROY LOCK AND DAM NY', ['2014', '02'], '20', '0', '-7', '12', '53', '4.08', '24.6', '22.2', '31.2', '13.4\n']]

Comment: can't reproduce the error with that content. You may want to use `for i, x in enumerate(tdlist):` and `print(i, x)` to see which entry `i` in the `tdlist` is causing the error

Comment: @downshift would it be a problem if the lists inside of the list occasionally were missing values and had empty strings in those positions, even though I have an if statement that addresses it?

Comment: @Mahone12345 I don't know, that's why we need to inspect the contents of the list more; but the if statement `if x != '':` may not be handling the case that's causing the error. That's what inspecting the `repr()` on each entry in `tdlist` can determine. I mean, an empty string can be more than `''`. Depends on if the contents are clean, meaning no hidden characters, or maybe it has two spaces, etc. `' ' != ''`

Answer (score 0):

You're error is here:

```
x[1][1]
```

when you do that, the first `x[1]` returns a string, and the second x[1][1] retunrs the second char in the string, so you have to change it to:

```
TMINlist = []
for pos in range(len(tdlist)):
    TMINlist.append(tdlist[pos][10])
TMINlist2 = []
for x in tdlist:
    if int(x[1]) == month: # here, you have to take the x[1], not x[1][1]
        if x != '':
            value = float(TMINlist[tdlist.index(x)])
            TMINlist2.append(value)
        else:
            continue
```

example:

considere this lists:

TMINlist = []
tdlist = [["0.4", "0.4", "0.4", "0.4"],["0.4", "0.4", "0.4", "0.4"]]
TMINlist2 = []

after run the code above, they will return:

```
   TMINlist2
=> [0.4, 0.4]
   TMINlist
=> ['0.4', '0.4']
   tdlist
=> [['0.4', '0.4', '0.4', '0.4'], ['0.4', '0.4', '0.4', '0.4']]
```

Comment: oh yeah sorry about that , I forgot to mention that that position specifically codes for a list inside of a list inside of the entire list, so changing it is not really an option

Comment: @Mahone12345 but I don't understand... why is not an option?

Comment: It's not an option because the list its probing is shaped like [[a,[b,c],d,e,f][a,[b,c],d,e,f]], and i specifically need the if statement to be if c = month (which is an input)